# Bald spots on model with hair particles

Tags: modeling, particles

I wanted to add fur to this model but there are some bald spots for some reason. Any ideas on how to fix this ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like for some reason the ngon you have at the top of your mesh, coupled with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, make the particle fail, you can fix that by creating quads:

[image]

Or enable the *Use Modifier Stack* which seems to fix the problem:

[image]

Or move the *Subdivision Surface* modifier below the *ParticleSystem*, but it may look bad:

[image]

Comment: I also would apply the scale (*Ctrl+A > Scale* in Object mode) since it's non-uniform, and set *Render Properties > Curves > Viewport Display > Shape* to *Strip* so you can see the rendered shape in the viewport.

Comment: @Blunder thanks for the additional infos  ;)